# PHP script to remove everything before the first occurrence of a number

Tags: php, regex, replace, str-replace

What I'm trying to remove all data in a string before a the first occurrence of a number like (1-9) maybe in a function?

example:

```
$value = removeEverythingBefore($value, '1-10');
```

SO if i have a test like "Hello I want to rule the world in 100 hours or so"

I want this to find the first occurrence of a number which is `1` and delete everything before it.

Leaving me with `100 hours or so`.

Comment: You should use a regex. You could use `preg_match`, or `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function like you mentioned in your post you can do like the below:

```
<?php
function removeEverythingBefore($value, $pattern) {
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $initialPosition = $matches[0][1];
    return substr($value, $initialPosition);
}

$value = "Hello I want to rule the world in 100 hours or so";
$value = removeEverythingBefore($value, '/[0-9]/');
echo $value; // prints 100 hours or so
```

This way you can use the same function to match other patters aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this with the regex `/([a-z\s]*)(?=\d)/i` like this:

```
$string = "Hello I want to rule the world in 100 hours or so";
$newString = preg_replace("/([a-z\s]*)(?=\d)/i", "", $string);
echo $newString; // Outputs "100 hours or so"
```

You can see an it working with [this eval.in](https://eval.in/645548). If you wanted it in a function you could use this:

```
function removeEverythingBeforeNumber($string)
{
    return preg_replace("/([a-z\s]*)(?=\d)/i", "", $string);
}
$newString = removeEverythingBeforeNumber("Hello I want to rule the world in 100 hours or so");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) to get the index of the first occurence and then [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) to get the string beginning from that index. Would be faster/more hardware friendly then regex i believe.

Comment: It could be any number so `strpos` wont work (unless you're going to do 10 `strpos` calls). `first occurrence of a number like (1-9) `